# Using 'display:block' in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Does anyone have some tips/tricks for dealing with IE quirks? I've got some code that works well in every other browser, but unfortunately it doesn't play nice in IE. I think I've narrowed it down to the `display:block` code that I'm using in CSS to modify the look of an ul to a navigation menu.

Every other browser treats the `display:block` as expected: the styling extends to the entire list "block". Here's the code I'm working with:

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
<ul id="main_ul">
    <li class="main_li">    
        <a class="hyper_nav" title="Home" href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="main_li">    
        <a class="active_nav" title="Link 1" href="link1.html">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="main_li">    
        <a class="hyper_nav" title="Link 2" href="link2.html">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="main_li">    
        <a class="hyper_nav" title="Link 3" href="link3.html">Link 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#main_ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
.main_li {
    width:165px;
    background:#a3dc32;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:7px 0px;
}
.main_li + .main_li {
    border-left:2px solid #ffffff;
}
.hyper_nav, .hyper_nav:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:block;
}
.hyper_nav:hover, .hyper_nav:visited, .active_nav, .active_nav:link, .active_nav:hover, .active_nav:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    background:#7F52A8;
    / color:#ffffff;
    padding:10px 0px;
    margin:-10px 0px;
}
```

And the fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qvfqwa3y/).

I do have the following code in my `head` tags, which I understand is supposed to get IE working properly with HTML5, but that's not solving anything:

```
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Can anyone offer any hints or advice, please?

Comment: A huge top-tip with browser differences from myself is to use Normalise before any other CSS script.

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Make sure you apply it before all other CSS, using this will prevent a LOT of problems we have when it comes to browsers.

Thanks! (Didn't mean to ANSWER, only meant to comment)

Comment: On your fiddle, I'm getting the same appearance on [Chrome](http://i.snag.gy/oMYJg.jpg) and [IE 11](http://i.snag.gy/URtmr.jpg) (and IE 9 for that matter). What exactly is the issue you are having?

Comment: IE11 doesn't use conditional comments anymore, so your `[if IE]` stuff won't work.

Comment: @Pinpickle Expand the output window to be large enough to fit all the items on one row. I don't have IE11 easily accessible to test, but it may reveal a difference (I'm guessing it won't, tho).

Comment: @ajp15243 too true! I've edited the original post with screenshots of "wide enough outputs". Result is still the same: no difference.

Comment: Sorry, should have included a screenshot myself: http://snag.gy/4r30q.jpg

The `display:block` code doesn't seem to extend to the entire element on links that are visited. Instead, there's a purple bar. My intent was to have visited and unvisited links as a green colour, and links that are hovered over will be purple. Also, when the user is on a particular page, that pages link will be purple. Hence the `active_nav`class.

But, if it's working for you, maybe its my version of IE11 in my virtual machine?

Comment: Rasm Frasm, I figured it out. Grouped the `hyper_nav:visited`class with the **wrong** other hyperlink classes. Of course it was displaying a purple background, not green! I'm blaming it on lack of sleep. 

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you target the `a` element it looks all the same also in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/qvfqwa3y/5/

```
.hyper_nav, .hyper_nav:link a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:block;
}
```